# Win Store Apps using Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, windows-store-apps

I was going through Win store apps and came to know that you can use HTML5 and CSS3.
A quick question (might be silly), can we build Win 8 Apps using Asp.Net (or MVC)? If yes, how can we target our output to Win 8 App output instead of browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, but such an option isn't available. If you think it through, it'd be significant engineering work. ASP.NET is designed to run on a server and dynamically adapt to the host browser. To target an app output would mean running the ASP.NET code as part of the compilation process to get app-specific HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. In addition, ASP.NET would have to be extended to provide access to WinRT APIs, but those are client APIs and not server-side APIs.